# Всем привет, как сделать,чтобы при наведении на картинки менялся цвет?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, как сделать,чтобы при наведении на картинки менялся цвет?

Comment: Не понятно где и как именно должен меняться цвет. Прикрепляй свой код для примера или подробнее опиши задачу. А в общем случае есть псевдокласс ":hover", который срабатывает, когда пользователь наводит на элемент мышью. Тогда ты можешь задать цвет этому элементу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  }

div::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

  div:hover::before{
    opacity: .5;
  }
```

```html
<div>
 <img src="photo-1.png">
</div>
```

Comment: картинки формата jpg,по вашему коду картинка не поменяла цвет,но под картинкой появился фон

Comment: А как вы хотите, чтобы сама картинка меняла цвет? Опишите более подробно

Comment: Да,хочу добавить на картинку градиент и прозрачность,чтобы картинка еще виднелась под эти цветом

Comment: И это по наведению мыши, верно?

Comment: да , все  верно,пи

Comment: Пробуйте мой код, я поменял немного